# How to Customize the Apple Watch Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I was just thinking, it is not possible at this time to change the color of the Vertical scrollbar in Apple Watch.

But I just saw the App on Apple site and here is the screen shot of the app

[image]

I want to change the color of the scrollbar from default to my desired color as the above picture shows green scrollbar scroller.

i found no way to access it, even in `WKWindowsFeatures` and not accessible in storyboard.

Global tint color is just for the

-The title string in the status bar

-The app name in short look notifications

**So how can i change it to my desired color.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to customize the scrollbar's color at this time. Any changes in color you see are controlled by the OS.

Comment: Yes. I've worked with WK extensively. Just read through the docs and you'll note the lack of any API for doing this.