# How to hide Digital Crown scroll indicator?

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, watchos

Is there a way to hide Digital Crown rotation indicator on Apple Watch using SwiftUI (or any other way)?

[image: app screenshot]
[image: thats what I'm trying to get rid off.]

Here is sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("uno")
            Text("uno")
            Text("uno")
            Text("uno")
            Text("uno")
            Text("uno")
        }
    }
}
```

(amazing isn't it?)

I can't find any equivalent for "hide indicator". Can somebody help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816817/how-to-customize-the-apple-watch-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Customize the Apple Watch Vertical Scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816817/how-to-customize-the-apple-watch-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to hide the indicator with a `List`, but you could choose to hide the indicator if you are using a `ScrollView` instead.

```js
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
  // ...
}
```